# createJDBCProvider different way

Tags: python, websphere, jython

i need to create jdbc provider different way

this step 1  is the way i am able to create jdbc provider on websphere server.
1)

```
AdminTask.createJDBCProvider(['-scope', 'Node='+node,
                                  '-databaseType', 'DB2', 
                                  '-providerType', 'DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider', ...
```

i need another way because i need to reuse values from xml to another codes
my  xml values which i used are defined like ...

````
 <type>Node</type> <scopename>somenode</scopename>```
  <type>Servernode</type> <scopename>Node:somenode/Server:someserver</scopename>
````

i use scope from oustide function with

```
scope = AdminConfig.getid('/Node:'+scope+'/')   
scope = AdminConfig.getid('/ServerCluster:'+scope+'/')
```

I tried to create jdbc in two different ways but none is sucessful...
this is first attempt

2)

```
n1 = ['name', j_name]
dtyp = ['databaseType', 'DB2']
protyp = ['providerType', 'DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider'] ...
jdbcAttrs = [n1, implCN, dtyp, protyp, desc, cpath]
AdminConfig.create('JDBCProvider', scope, jdbcAttrs)
```

but error  was  **Invalid attributes specified for type "JDBCProvider" -- "databaseType"**
it can create only class name and name... it is interactive way

my second try was to define pure scope which i get from outside function,  that scope works on creating active specifications, shared libraries etc... which is logical because jython code for them is defined like that...

3)

`AdminTask.createJDBCProvider(['-scope', scope, '-databaseType', 'DB2' ,'-providerType', 'DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider' ...`

but it didnt work, and here was the error configuration data type is not valid

[image]

on ibm forum  configuration ID is the same as my..

is there any way i can avoid creating jdbc like in step 1

Answer (score 1):

I have found the easiest way to programmatically set items would be to use string formatting both for readability and serviceability. For Example:

```py
AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node={node},Server={server} -databaseType DB2 -providerType "DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider" -implementationType "XA data source" -name "DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider (XA)" -classpath [/work/drivers/db2jcc.jar] -nativePath "" ]'.format(node=xmlParser.get(node), server=xmlParser.get(server)))
```